# Loading `status` objects from File?

Tags: python, tweepy

A few months ago, I started grabbing Tweets from twitter for a data analysis project. I used Tweepy and python3.3 to get the status objects and dump them to a file, one file per day.

I mostly did this because I only wanted to quickly gather data, however I'm facing this problem:

Since the status objects are now strings, I cannot convert them back using tweepy - as far as I can tell - by loading them from my files.

Which sucks, because I now realize I truly only need the `status._json` part of the object. For whatever reason I thought otherwise 3 months ago.

My question is this:

Is there a known way of converting these `status` objects back from strings ?

I have checked `Tweepy` docs and googled about, and I am pretty sure that this is not possible by given tools.

The only alternative I can see is to split the string manually, which seems pretty ugly.

**Example** of a status object saved in my file:
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eQEi62y4)

These are stored per line, by simply appending them to the file each time a new one is grabbed from twitter.

Comment: Can you give an example how those files look? How did you save them?

Comment: I've added it as a pastebin link - the lines are very long. They were saved my simply writing them to a file, using the `open(file, 'a')` option.

Comment: Maybe you could try running `eval` on them, after importing relevant classes, modules from Tweepy?

Comment: I've imported all modules I used during the inital mining, calling `eval(status)` returns a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Yeah I tried it too. The text isn't really continuous at places. Also, I don't think it would be possible. For example, at certain places, I see this: `tweepy.api.API object at 0x7f6fd798fe10`. I'm pretty sure now you can't get the `_api` object forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the answer you're expecting, but might give a starting point.

I took one instance of your `Status` record, put it in a [text file](https://dpaste.de/sxEz), and ran this script:

```
# coding: utf-8

with open('status.txt') as f:
    tco = f.read()

import re
re.compile("(?P<key>\w+)=(?P<value>\w+)")
expre = re.compile("(?P<key>\w+)=(?P<value>\w+)")
pairs = dict(re.findall(expre, tco))
```

And this gives you something like this:

```
{'author': 'User',
 'contributors': 'None',
 'contributors_enabled': 'False',
 'coordinates': 'None',
 'created_at': 'datetime',
 'default_profile': 'True',
 'default_profile_image': 'False',
 'favorite_count': '0',
 'favorited': 'False',
 'favourites_count': '46',
 'follow_request_sent': 'None',
 'followers_count': '204',
 'following': 'False',
 'friends_count': '274',
 'geo': 'None',
 'geo_enabled': 'True',
 'id': '652242063048724480',
 'in_reply_to_screen_name': 'None',
 'in_reply_to_status_id': 'None',
 'in_reply_to_status_id_str': 'None',
 'in_reply_to_user_id': 'None',
 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': 'None',
 'is_quote_status': 'False',
 'is_translator': 'False',
 'listed_count': '91',
 'location': 'None',
 'notifications': 'None',
 'place': 'None',
 'possibly_sensitive': 'False',
 'profile_background_tile': 'False',
 'profile_use_background_image': 'True',
 'protected': 'False',
 'retweet_count': '0',
 'retweeted': 'False',
 'statuses_count': '9724',
 'truncated': 'False',
 'user': 'User',
 'utc_offset': '7200',
 'verified': 'False'}
```

Now obviously, this is missing a lot of information my simple regex couldn't parse. `User` object attributes, for example. Some json dicts also.

For more complicated things that are in your problem at hand, I'd advise you to look into `parser` module. I'll see what I can do in my free time to get around this though. Seems like a good problem.

Comment: I was, in fact, expecting someone would suggest using regular expressions - the pointer to the `parser` module helps though. Cheers mate!

Comment: Glad that was helpful.